# Any free software to compute boolean expression?

Tags: software

I found a few but they cannot evaluate long expressions. For long expressions they give me boolean values for each individual sub expressions (which is usually grouped by parentheses).

((A v B) + (~A v ~B)) v ((C v D) + (~C v ~D)) v ((E v F) + (~E v ~F)) v ((G v H) + (~G v ~H)) v ((I v J) + (~I v ~J)) v ((K v L) + (~K v ~L)) v ((M v N) + (~M v ~N)) v ((P v Q) + (~P v ~Q))

This is the kind of expression I need to evaluate. It will give me 2^16 ~ 65k rows.

I used this [website](http://www.brian-borowski.com/Software/Truth/), but doesn't seem giving me the final column.

Oh. I don't want to compile the program myself... 
Thank you very much!

Comment: evaluate or simplify? evaluation is a relatively easy problem, whereas simplification is, I believe, rather more difficult.

Comment: Yeah just evaluation. Thanks anyway, Jeff :3

Comment: @JustJeff minimization is difficult, but Espresso is quite good at it :o)

Comment: (Takes mod hat off) I think it's hilarious that both answers here get around the "I don't want to compile the program myself" restriction by using Python. (Puts mod hat back on)

Comment: @vicatu - to clarify, I meant minimization is difficult in the computer-science sense of the word, not that it can't be done, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This Python procedure will evaluate a formula in your format (first argument) against a list of single-letter variables (second argument):

```
def table( x, v , w = "" ):
   if( v == "" ):
      print( "%s : %d " % ( w, eval( x.replace( "v", " or " ).replace( "~", " ! " ).replace( "+", " and " ))))
   else:
      table( x.replace( v[ 0 ], "0" ), v[ 1 : ], w + "0" )
      table( x.replace( v[ 0 ], "1" ), v[ 1 : ], w + "1" )
```

for example

```
table( "(A v B ) + ~ C", "ABC" )
```

produces

```
000 : 0 
001 : 0 
010 : 1 
011 : 0 
100 : 1 
101 : 0 
110 : 1 
111 : 0
```

To get your answer, evaluate

```
X = "((A v B) + (~A v ~B)) v ((C v D) + (~C v ~D)) v ((E v F) + (~E v ~F)) v ((G v H) + (~G v ~H)) v ((I v J) + (~I v ~J)) v ((K v L) + (~K v ~L)) v ((M v N) + (~M v ~N)) v ((P v Q) + (~P v ~Q))"
table( X, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQ" )
```

Comment: Hi Wouter. Your script is brilliant. Thanks. I want to mention that the "not" operator, "!" is sensitive to space. It requires a space between the "!" and the letter that follows it. 

>>>
for demo purpose
# table( "( ( ~ A + ~ B ) v ( A + B ) ) +( ( ~ C + ~ D ) v ( C + D ) )", "ABCD" )

Thanks!

Comment: so always add spaces :],  and to help reading better, add a pair of single quoting marks to %d. ==>    print( "%s : '%d'" % ( w, eval( x.replace( "v", "or" ).replace( "~", "not" ).replace( "+", "and" ))))

Comment: Funny, those spaces where there in the code that I cut-n-pasted in my answer. Maybe lost in the first posting, because I then did not format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python module that uses a different notation for boolean expressions. It is the notation used in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form_%28Boolean_algebra%29 where there is an implicit AND between adjacent variables, `+` means OR, and a trailing single quote `'` inverts whatever it comes after. So, `(A v B ) + ~ C` in Wouter's example would be written as `(a + b)c'`

To print the truth table of the expression, call the module as:

```
>>> printtruth("(a+b)c'")
a b c F
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
```

The module itself:

```
def parsebool(s):
    tokens = list()
    allvars = set()
    paridx = list()
    lastpar = None
    for i, char in enumerate(s):
        if char == "'":
            if len(tokens) == 0:
                raise ValueError("cannot negate empty expression")
            elif tokens[-1] == ")":
                tokens.insert(lastpar, "not")
            else:
                tokens.insert(-1, "not")
        elif char == "(":
            if tokens and not (tokens[-1] in ("or", "and", "(")):
                # implicit and
                tokens.append("and")
            paridx.append(len(tokens))
            tokens.append("(")
        elif char == ")":
            tokens.append(")")
            lastpar = paridx.pop()
        elif char.islower() or char == '0' or char == '1':
            if tokens and not (tokens[-1] in ("or", "and", "(")):
                # implicit and
                tokens.append("and")
            if char.islower():
                allvars.add(char)
            tokens.append(char)
        elif char == "+":
            tokens.append("or")
        elif char == "*":
            tokens.append("and")
        elif char in " \t\n":
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError("invalid character in input: \"%s\"", char)
    return tokens, allvars

def boolfunc(s, name="F"):
    tokens, allvars = parsebool(s)
    allvars = list(sorted(allvars))
    lambdastr = "lambda %s: %s" % (','.join(allvars), ' '.join(tokens))
    F = eval(lambdastr, {'__builtins__':None}, {})
    F.func_doc = 'Boolean function %s(%s) = %s' % (name, ', '.join(allvars), s)
    F.func_name = name
    return F

def printtruth(F):
    if not callable(F):
        F = boolfunc(F)

    varnames = F.func_code.co_varnames
    Fname = F.func_name
    allnames = varnames + (Fname,)
    rowfmt = " ".join("%% %ds" % len(v) for v in allnames)
    print " ".join(allnames)
    for args in itertools.product((0,1), repeat=len(varnames)):
        try:
            result = str(int(F(*args)))
        except Exception:
            result = "E"
        print rowfmt % (args + (result,))

def printcompare(F, G):
    if not callable(F):
        F = boolfunc(F)
    if not callable(G):
        G = boolfunc(G)

    Fvarnames = F.func_code.co_varnames
    Fname = F.func_name
    Gvarnames = G.func_code.co_varnames
    Gname = G.func_name

    varnames = tuple(sorted(frozenset(Fvarnames).union(Gvarnames)))
    allnames = varnames + (Fname, Gname, "=")
    rowfmt = " ".join("%% %ds" % len(v) for v in allnames)
    print " ".join(allnames)

    allequals = True
    for args in itertools.product((0,1), repeat=len(varnames)):
        argdict = dict(zip(varnames, args))
        Fargs = [argdict[n] for n in Fvarnames]
        Gargs = [argdict[n] for n in Gvarnames]
        try:
            Fresult = str(int(F(*Fargs)))
        except Exception:
            Fresult = "E"
        try:
            Gresult = str(int(G(*Gargs)))
        except Exception:
            Gresult = "E"
        equals = Fresult == Gresult
        allequals = allequals and equals
        print rowfmt % (args + (Fresult,Gresult,equals))

    if allequals:
        print "functions are equivalent"
    else:
        print "functions are NOT EQUIVALENT"
```